# FactoryGirl polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, factory-bot

I can't create a valid comment factory using factory girl. My comment model belongs to commentable and is polymorphic.  I've tried a whole bunch of different things, but at the moment, most of my tests are failing with this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
    Validation failed: User can't be blank, Outlet can't be blank
```

I'm not sure why it isn't passing validation, especially because my comment model validates the presence of user_id and outlet_id, not User and Outlet

Here is my factory:

```
factory :comment do
    body "This is a comment"
    association :outlet_id, factory: :outlet
    association :user_id, factory: :user
    #outlet_id factory: :outlet
    association :commentable, factory: :outlet
end
```

---

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @comment = Comment.new
end

def create
    @outlet = Outlet.find(params[:outlet_id])
    @comment = @outlet.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = User.find(params[:user_id]).id


    if @comment.save
        redirect_to(@outlet)
    end
end

def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

    if @comment.update(comment_params)
        redirect_to @comment.outlet
    end
end

def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

    if @comment.destroy
        redirect_to @comment.outlet
    end
end


private
def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :outlet_id, :user_id)
end
```

end

---

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true

   validates :body, :user_id, :outlet_id, presence: true
   validates :body, length: { in: 1..1000 }
end
```

---

Comment: what happens if you remove the validation `validates :user_id, :outlet_id, presence: true` ?

Comment: the test will pass, but i feel like I should be validating that each comment has a user_id and outlet_id that it belongs to, no?

Comment: yup, but i don't understand why don't you use the models instead of the ids

Comment: When I change the validation to user and outlet then the error I get for why I don't have a valid factory is:  NoMethodError:
        undefined method `user' for #<Comment:0x007f9a7e45b058>
        Did you mean?  user_id

Comment: but you should define the association in the the model `Comment` first, like you do with `commentable`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. do you mean to also add lines that say belongs_to user and belongs_to outlet in my Comment.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason for using `association :user_id`?

You probably want something more like:

```
factory :comment do
    body "This is a comment"
    association :outlet, factory: :outlet
    association :user, factory: :user
    association :commentable, factory: :outlet
end
```

Which incidentally can simplify to:

```
factory :comment do
    body "This is a comment"
    outlet
    user
    association :commentable, factory: :outlet
end
```

Comment: yes, the reason why I was using user_id was because I was getting a no method error saying that comment does not have a method "user"

Comment: @HarryB. you could add `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :outlet` to `Comment`? I'm trying to understand why you're referencing the `_id` fields directly here.